# Python envisage framework

Tags: python, user-interface, frameworks, enthought

I just started with envisage framework. In the 4.x version I saw a few example, but I need a good documentation: [link](http://github.enthought.com/envisage/).

How can I add custom buttons to the envisage workbench, or how can I create a similar one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place look for documentation is the [Acmelab example](https://github.com/enthought/envisage/tree/master/examples/plugins/workbench/AcmeLab) in the Envisage source tree.

I'm assuming when you talk about custom buttons you mean buttons on a toolbar.  First you need to create a WorkbenchActionSet, add your toolbar there, and then define your actions and assign them a button image.  Here is the (slightly modified) Acmelab example with non-relevant parts taken out:

test_action_set.py

```
# Enthought library imports.
from envisage.ui.action.api import Action, Group, Menu, ToolBar
from envisage.ui.workbench.api import WorkbenchActionSet


class TestActionSet(WorkbenchActionSet):
    """ An action test useful for testing. """

    #### 'ActionSet' interface ################################################

    tool_bars = [
        ToolBar(name='Fred', groups=['AToolBarGroup']),
        ToolBar(name='Wilma'),
        ToolBar(name='Barney')
    ]

    actions = [
        Action(
            path='ToolBar',
            class_name='acme.workbench.action.new_view_action:NewViewAction'
        ),]
```

new_view_action.py

```
""" An action that dynamically creates and adds a view. """


# Enthought library imports.
from pyface.api import ImageResource
from pyface.action.api import Action
from pyface.workbench.api import View


class NewViewAction(Action):
    """ An action that dynamically creates and adds a view. """

    #### 'Action' interface ###################################################

    # A longer description of the action.
    description = 'Create and add a new view'

    # The action's name (displayed on menus/tool bar tools etc).
    name = 'New View'

    # A short description of the action used for tooltip text etc.
    tooltip = 'Create and add a new view'

    image = ImageResource(Your Image File Name Goes Here)

    ###########################################################################
    # 'Action' interface.
    ###########################################################################

    def perform(self, event):
        """ Perform the action. """
    # You can give the view a position... (it default to 'left')...
    view = View(id='my.view.fred', name='Fred', position='right')
    self.window.add_view(view)

    # or you can specify it on the call to 'add_view'...
    view = View(id='my.view.wilma', name='Wilma')
    self.window.add_view(view, position='top')

    return

#### EOF ######################################################################
```

Comment: I want to create a user interface, with buttons, we are receiving datas from the sensors, and we want some buttons with actions(tasks) and we want to use Mayavi for plotting, we chose this framework because the plugin system, but unfortunately not a well documented framework.

Comment: In that case, you probably want to use something based on TraitsUI.  http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits/docs/html/TUIUG/index.html

Comment: Is it possible to extend with plugins?

Comment: I just found this introduction http://www.aero.iitb.ac.in/~prabhu/tmp/python_cep07/course_handouts/envisage_handout.pdf , unfortunately this simple example is compatible only with the 2.x version. I'm using 4.0.1, I tried to get work without any success.

Comment: You can create TraitsUI interfaces that can be used as Envisage plugins.  There's another example in the Envisage source tree called Lorenz at https://github.com/enthought/envisage/tree/master/examples/plugins/workbench/Lorenz .  The file lorenz_ui_plugin.py at https://github.com/enthought/envisage/blob/master/examples/plugins/workbench/Lorenz/acme/lorenz/lorenz_ui_plugin.py contains TraitsUI views used with the Envisage workbench.

Comment: It's a really powerful framework, I like it but they need a good documentation, for example for the trac(web-based project management and bug-tracking tool) have a really good documentation.

Comment: Well, Envisage is still very much a work in progress.  They have generated documentation in the past, but it's changing so quickly that the docs are quickly out of date.